# dividing an array into 3 individual arrays

Tags: delphi, delphi-7, dynamic-arrays

I have 45 values stored in an array, `sample`. It needs to be split into three individual arrays of size 15, `sample1`, `sample2` and `sample3`: the first 15 items into `sample1`, the next 15 into `sample2` and the remaining 15 into `sample3`. I tried to do that with this code:

```
var
  sample: array of integer; // Source Array which contains data
  sample1, sample2, sample3: array of integer; //Target arrays which needs to be worked upon
  i: integer;
begin
 SetLength(sample1, 15);
 SetLength(sample2, 15);
 SetLength(sample3, 15); 
 for i := 0 to 14 do
   sample[i] := sample1[i];
 for i:= 15 to 29 do
   sample[i] := sample2[i];  
 for i:= 30 to 44 do
   sample[i] := sample3[i];
 i := i + 1;
```

I am able to get the results in the first array, but not in the other arrays. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to offset the index of the source array. *e.g.*, `... := sample2[i-15]`. Otherwise, you're indexing it incorrectly (from 15 to 29).

Comment: I have done indexing before but still it doesn't work

Comment: Your code as shown has other issues, or at least incomplete. such as the length of `sample` isn't being set, and there's no loop. Please show the actual code you have tried most recently without fragmentation.

Comment: If you "did indexing" before, and it didn't work, you did it wrong. Rather than reject @lurker's accurate comment, you should heed it. You don't appear to be splitting in any case, rather you are merging. There is so much wrong in the question though. Just including random lines whilst omitting key details does not help. The incrementing of `i` is inexplicable. It seems like you are trying to do this by trial and error. Do yourself a favour and learn the value of a [mcve].

Comment: Splitting is trivial, but how do you want to split? `123123123...` or `11111222223333` do you want to sort the array having all minimum values in 1 array, all max in another and the middle ones in the final array? Right now we can give you a solution, and then you'll do a come-back and say: "no no that's not what I meant". Please state **exactly** what you're trying to achieve. Should all array be the same size (and thus allow duplicate values in an array if need be) or will you allow result array of differing size (if so which array)?

Comment: As @David said, you are not splitting, you are trying to merge, or concatenate (you are assigning in the wrong direction). And as some have said, your indexes for the smaller arrays are off. To split, do something like `for i := 15 to 29 do sample2[i - 15] := sample[i];`, etc.

Comment: It seems to me that this is not your real code. Don't post fake code, as it is impossible to see if an error in your fake code is really an error in your real code too. And what does "I have done indexing before" mean? And why is there an `i := i + 1;` at the end? `i`'s value is undefined after the loops, and inside a for-loop you can't change the loop index variable. Your code, as shown here, makes no sense.

Comment: FWIW You might want to consider ***why*** you're trying to split in the first place. Often splitting is just a waste of time. If you want to work on 3 parts of the source array separately, it may be better to write your code to take the range of entries to use as extra parameters. E.g. `procedure DoWork2(ASource: array of Integer; AFromIndex, AToIndex: Integer);` And call it as follows: `DoWork2(sample, 15, 29);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you well, the following is what you want. I assume your `sample` array has exactly 45 items, so you probably want to do this:

```
var 
  sample: array of Integer;
  sample1, sample2, sample3: array of Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(sample, 45);
  { fill sample with values }
  ...
  { now split: }
  SetLength(sample1, 15);
  SetLength(sample2, 15);
  SetLength(sample3, 15);
  for i := 0 to 14 do
  begin
    sample1[i] := sample[i];
    sample2[i] := sample[i + 15]; { i = 0..14, so i+15 = 15..29 }
    sample3[i] := sample[i + 30]; { i = 0..14, so i+30 = 30..44 } 
  end;
```

That should do the trick. If this is not what you wanted, then you should specify your problem a bit better. If you `sample` array is longer, this won't split all of it. If your `sample` array is shorter, you'll get an overflow, causing an error or undefined behaviour.

Comment: I've removed all the comments here, because they were getting out of hand. I will say this, though: berating an answerer who is just trying to be helpful is not something I appreciate.

Comment: @Brad Understood. I personally don't think that answering poor questions without fixing the question is actually helpful to the site. Perhaps I need to accept the declining quality of SO questions.

Comment: FWIW, I did edit the question to make it more understandable. But I did not, of course, change the code.

Answer (score 3):

You are assigning the target arrays to the source array, instead of the other way around. And you are using the wrong indexing anyway.

Try something more like this instead:

```
var
  sample: array of integer;
  sample1, sample2, sample3: array of integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(sample1, 15);
  SetLength(sample2, 15);
  SetLength(sample3, 15); 
  for i := 0 to 14 do
    sample1[i] := sample[i];
  for i := 0 to 14 do
    sample2[i] := sample[15+i];  
  for i := 0 to 14 do
    sample3[i] := sample[30+i];
  ...
```

Alternatively:

```
var
  sample: array of integer;
  sample1, sample2, sample3: array of integer;
  i: integer;
begin
  ...
  SetLength(sample1, 15);
  SetLength(sample2, 15);
  SetLength(sample3, 15); 
  for i := 0 to 14 do
  begin
    sample1[i] := sample[i];
    sample2[i] := sample[15+i];  
    sample3[i] := sample[30+i];
  end;
  ...
```

Since your target arrays are dynamic anyway, I would suggest using `Copy()` instead of any manual loops at all:

```
var
  sample, sample1, sample2, sample3: array of integer;
begin
 ...
 sample1 := Copy(sample, 0, 15);
 sample2 := Copy(sample, 15, 15);
 sample3 := Copy(sample, 30, 15);
```

Comment: I don't think `Copy()` can do this (start index, etc.) in in older versions, like Delphi 7, which the OP seems to be using. But I can't check, since I have no D7 installed anymore.

Comment: WIW, in your first code snippet, there is one `begin` too many (end of second `for`).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Yes it can. In fact Copy() method hasn't changed much since Turbo Pascal where it is able to accept same parameters as in newest versions of Delphi.

Comment: @SilverWarrior: `Copy` **has** changed since Turbo Pascal. Turbo Pascal did not have dynamic arrays, and IIRC, `Copy` did not work on dynamic arrays, originally, not even in Delphi 4 (when dynarrays were introduced). But did you actually try this in Delphi 7, or do you just think so?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: I have D7 and can confirm that `Copy()` works for splitting a dynamic array (but not a static or open array).

Comment: @Remy: OK, thanks. I do think I remember it was not always possible, but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Remy: FWIW, copy is indeed the most elegant solution, especially because it doesn't require loops or `SetLength`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: You were correct, i was wrongly assigning the other way round. I am new and after watching the solution thought was so dumb to notice

Comment: @delsql: How come you said it worked? Is this your real code?

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: The solution i meant in my above comment was,  i tried using the code provided by you and Remy Lebeau and got to know my mistake. Thanks!